# Can't create translucent window

Tags: java, swing, jframe, transparency

I'm trying to make translucent window, I've read many posts that say that it doesn't work in Java 7 at all, some solved this problem, but their ways don't work for me. If I try to make panel translucent, background just bacomes darker. Here's my class:

```java
public class MainCycle {
    public static DrawPanel drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
              JFrame frame = new JFrame();
              JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);

              GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
              GraphicsDevice gd = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
              System.out.println(gd.isWindowTranslucencySupported(WindowTranslucency.TRANSLUCENT));
              frame.setOpacity(0.75f);

              frame.setUndecorated(true);
              frame.setBounds(0, 0, (int)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth(), (int)Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight());
              frame.setContentPane(drawPanel);
              frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
              frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Output:

```java
true
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.IllegalComponentStateException: The frame is decorated
at java.awt.Frame.setOpacity(Unknown Source)
at com.bg.my_paint_program.MainCycle$1.run(MainCycle.java:31)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Can you help me someway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Move the below line before calling `frame.setOpacity(0.75f);`

```
frame.setUndecorated(true);
```

Comment: Don't remove it just a placement of this line. Basically the problem is at `setOpacity()` method. You have to call  `frame.setUndecorated(true);` before `setOpacity()` method.